# Assign subcategories to a new parent - possible to retrofit those to relate to the new parent?

Tags: categories

I created a category and subcategories tied to this category. I then created a new category and then went into the old "main" category and assigned this new category as the previous 'top' category as its parent. From the look of it, the subcategories aren't aware that they have a new parent (in the admin, nothing comes up in the listing pages as being children of this new parent category. Same goes for the front-end of the site).

Any way to have EE run through and re-detect who the parents are? In the attached image, "Handouts" is the newly created parent category - you can see that it has a much higher number than the old "parent" which was Departments and Work Areas

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Have you reported it to EllisLab?

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it seems like it would be a bug, otherwise there should be documents stating that you need to create categories linearly and not change them, nor should EE give you the option to re-parent categories. I filed a bug with EllisLab https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20655/categories-children-do-not-inherit-their-new-parent-when-parent-is-assigned